# Try to calculate matrix but get RangeError (index): Index out of range: no indices are valid: 0

Tags: dart

I am still new with dart, so I'm trying to figure things out. Right now, I tried to create matrix and calculate using this formula.

```
import 'dart:math';
​
void main() {
  List<List<double>> normalisasi = new List<List<double>>();
​
 List<List<double>> data = [
    [10000000, 35, 110, 7],
    [12000000, 45, 125, 6],
    [15000000, 40, 150, 8],
    [14000000, 37.5, 125, 7.5],
  ];
​
  var bobot = [0.35, 0.25, 0.15, 0.25];
​
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
      normalisasi[i][j] = data[i][j] / (pow(data[j][i], 2));
      print(normalisasi[i][j]);
    }
  }
}
```

But I get this instead:

> RangeError (index): Index out of range: no indices are valid: 0

Please help me, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your normalisasi List is growable, therefore you need to use the 'add()' function to grow it. Alternatively, you can specify the fixed dimensions of the arrays on creation.

See [fixed-size vs growable lists](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/dart_programming/dart_programming_lists.htm)